# MySQL performance - Selecting and deleting from a large table

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a large table called "queue". It has 12 million records right now.

```
CREATE TABLE `queue` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `target` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `errors` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_unique` (`userid`,`action`,`target`),
  KEY `idx_userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `idx_state` (`state`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Multiple PHP workers (150) use this table simultaneously.

They select a record, perform a network request using the selected data and then delete the record.

I get mixed execution times from the select and delete queries. Is the delete command locking the table?

What would be the best approach for this scenario?

1. SELECT record + NETWORK request + DELETE the record
2. SELECT record + NETWORK request + MARK record as completed + DELETE completed records using a cron from time to time (I don't want an even bigger table).

Note: The queue gets new records every minute but the INSERT query is not the issue here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're using a database as a queue, and working on it from multiple clients, you're bound to run into lock contention. Everyone struggles with this when they try to use a database as a queue. Instead, you should use some real message queue software, not a database. Something like ActiveMQ or Beanstalkd or RabbitMQ or Resque.

Comment: You may find it helpful to read this, especiallly the part on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Then you may want to [edit] your question to give more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Don't queue it, just do it".  That is, if the tasks are rather fast, it is better to simply perform the action and not queue it.  Databases don't make good queuing mechanisms.

`DELETE` does not lock an InnoDB table.  However, you can write a `DELETE` that seems that naughty.  Let's see your actual SQL so we can work in improving it.

12M records?  That's a huge backlog; what's up?

Shrink the datatypes so that the table is not gigabytes:

- `action` is only a small set of possible values?  Normalize it down to a 1-byte `ENUM` or `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.
- Ditto for `state` -- surely it does not need a 4-byte code?
- There is no need for `INDEX(userid)` since there is already an index (`UNIQUE`) starting with `userid`.
- If `state` has only a few value, the index won't be used.  Let's see your enqueue and dequeue queries so we can discuss how to either get rid of that index or make it 'composite' (and useful).
- What's the current value of `MAX(id)`?  Is it threatening to exceed your current limit of about 4 billion for `INT UNSIGNED`?
- How does PHP use the queue?  Does it hang onto an item via an InnoDB transaction?  That defeats any parallelism!  Or does it change `state`.  Show us the code; perhaps the lock & unlock can be made less invasive.  It should be possible to run a single autocommitted `UPDATE` to grab a row and its `id`.  Then, later, do an autocommitted `DELETE` with very little impact.
- I do not see a good index for grabbing a pending item.  Again, let's see the code.
- 150 seems like a lot -- have you experimented with *fewer*?  They *may* be stumbling over each other.
- Is the Slowlog turned on (with a low value for `long_query_time`)?  If so, I wonder what is the 'worst' query.  In situations like this, the answer may be surprising.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. First I'll try to implemented some of the suggested changes and will come back with some results. Thank you again!

Comment: * Column action has only 7 possible values
* Column  state has only 2 possible values
* Max(id) is around 64577039
* The workers only peform tasks for userid % 150 = 0 (they don't overlap their work)
* I need so many workers to get that huge queue executed, as each operation takes around 2 seconds, and new operations are added to the queue constantly

Comment: Are you I/O-bound?  CPU-bound?  Both?  Are the workers on the same machine?  One other machine?  Several other machines?  You are consuming 150 items every 2 seconds?  Is that the rate at which they are enqueued?

Comment: Why not delete immediately, without the delayed cron task?

Comment: @RobertNeagu - and, anything from the slowlog?